# SIMILAR TO not work with round round bracket in postgresql

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have used similar for match record but when I have "()" in string then I didn't get data in a query

```
select * from table_name where column SIMILAR TO '%(ICL-005(A)-1/2|IBL-006(A)-1/2)%'
```

if I use **LIKE** then it works but I want to match multiple patterns in a single query so
how I can get this data with **SIMILAR**

```
Database data

column
ICL-005(A) -- should not match
ICL-005(A)-1/2 -- should match
ICL-005(A)-2/2 -- should not match
IBL-006(A) -- should not match
IBL-006(A)-1/2 -- should match
```

in the above query, I didn't get any data

Comment: What do you want to happen?  Please provide example data, both of things that should match and things that should not.

Comment: I have updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO-REGEXP) `SIMILAR TO` uses a kind of regular expression where the parentheses denote capturing groups. As you want to include them in matched string, you need to escape them using `\`

```
SIMILAR TO '%(ICL-005\(A\)-1/2|IBL-006\(A\)-1/2)%'
```